# MS SQL : Create GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

Need to find count of records from table based on date.

Column is declared as date . Eg. 2021-06-09 17:25:18.987

Every second there is multiple records inserted into table.

Please give me a query to find total records for each date with group by clause yyyy-mm-dd.

Sample table

```
Name, registertime
A      2021-06-09 17:25:18.987
B      2021-06-01 15:25:18.987
A      2021-05-09 17:25:18.987
B      2021-06-01 17:25:18.987
A      2021-06-02 17:25:18.987
B      2021-06-03 17:25:18.987
A      2021-06-03 17:25:18.987
B      2021-06-03 17:25:18.987
```

Expected outcome

```
Date.                  Count
2021-05-09        1
2021-06-01        2
2021-06-02        1
2021-06-03        3
2021-06-09        1
```

Comment: Group by is a good place to start. What have you tried? If you add some sample data, sample code and your current/desired output - you'll be more likely to get a response

Comment: *"Please give me a query"* Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service. What have ***you*** tried to solve the problem? Why didn't ***your*** attempts worked? What have ***you*** done to try debug the failed attempts?

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far. Then people will help you to correct/improve your query. However, it is not a platform to get answers without trying anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply cast your column into date then use group by

```
select cast(date_column as date) ,count(*)
from yourtable
group by cast(date_column as date)
order by cast(date_column as date);
```

Above query will create a single row for each day with that day's count and in ascending order of dates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will resolve your issue, but you can try this:
`SELECT COUNT(*) AS HOW_MANY_TIMES, date_column  FROM your_table group by date_column;`

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But it should not work. You might missed that the column is of datetime and OP need data to be grouped by date only.